# insert json data into postgresql table using python

Tags: python, postgresql

I need to write an automated python code to create database table having column names as the keys from the json file and column data should be the values of those respective key.
My json looks like this:

```
    {
"Table_1": [
    {
        "Name": "B"
    }, 
    {
        "BGE3": [
            "Itm2", 
            "Itm1", 
            "Glass"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "Trans": []
    }, 
    {
        "Art": [
            "SYS"
        ]
    }]}
```

My table name should be: Table_1.

So my column name should look like:    Name |    BGE3 | Trans | Art.

And data should be its respected values.
Creation of table and columns has to be dynamic because I need to run this code on multiple json file.
So far I have managed to connect to the postgresql database using python.
So please help me with the solutions.Thankyou.

Postgres version 13.

Existing code:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Table_1(Name varchar, BGE3 varchar, Trans varchar, Art varchar)") 

for d in data: cur.execute("INSERT into B_Json_3(Name, BGE3, Trans , Art) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,)", d)
```

Where data is a list of arrays i made which can only be executed for this json. I need a function that will execute any json i want that can have 100 elements of list in the values of any key.

Comment: Really needs more information. Postgres version? Python version? What Python Postgres driver? The connection code? Add this information to your question. In meantime take a look at [Json](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#module-json) module in Python.

Comment: Postgres version is 13.

Comment: Python version is 3.7 (I am using pycharm IDE). this is how i connected: conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "postgres", user = "postgres", password = "hoelscher", host = "localhost", port = "5432")
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
cur.close()

Comment: cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Table_1(Name varchar, BGE3 varchar, Trans varchar, Art varchar);")
for d in data:
    cur.execute("INSERT into B_Json_3(Name, BGE3, Trans , Art) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,)", d)

Comment: where data is a list of arrays i made which can only be executed for this json. I need a function that will execute any json i want that can have 100 elements of list in the values of any key.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do with data? Do each of the elements in `"BGE3": ["Itm2",  "Itm1",  "Glass"]` go in a separate record or in one record? An example of how you want the data to appear in the table is needed.
        ]

Answer (score 0):

The table creation portion, using Python `json` module to convert JSON to Python dict and `psycopg2.sql` module to dynamically `CREATE TABLE`:

```
import json
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

tbl_json = """{
"Table_1": [
    {
        "Name": "B"
    }, 
    {
        "BGE3": [
            "Itm2", 
            "Itm1", 
            "Glass"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "Trans": []
    }, 
    {
        "Art": [
            "SYS"
        ]
    }]}
"""
# Transform JSON string into Python dict. Use json.load if pulling from file.
# Pull out table name and column names from dict.
tbl_dict = json.loads(tbl_json)
tbl_name = list(tbl_dict)[0]
tbl_name 
'Table_1'

col_names = [list(col_dict)[0] for col_dict in tbl_dict[tbl_name]]
# Result of above.
col_names
['Name', 'BGE3', 'Trans', 'Art']

# Create list of types and then combine column names and column types into 
# psycopg2 sql composed object. Warning: sql.SQL() does no escaping so potential 
# injection risk.
type_list = ["varchar", "varchar", "varchar"]
col_type = []
for i in zip(map(sql.Identifier, col_names), map(sql.SQL,type_list)):
    col_type.append(i[0] + i[1])
# The result of above.
col_type
[Composed([Identifier('Name'), SQL('varchar')]),
 Composed([Identifier('BGE3'), SQL('varchar')]),
 Composed([Identifier('Trans'), SQL('varchar')])]

# Build psycopg2 sql string using above.
sql_str = sql.SQL("CREATE table {} ({})").format(sql.Identifier(tbl_name), sql.SQL(',').join(col_type) )
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost user=aklaver")
cur = con.cursor()
# Shows the CREATE statement that will be executed.
print(sql_str.as_string(con))
CREATE table "Table_1" ("Name"varchar,"BGE3"varchar,"Trans"varchar)

# Execute statement and commit.
cur.execute(sql_str)
con.commit()

# In psql client the result of the execute:
 \d "Table_1" 
                   Table "public.Table_1"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 Name   | character varying |           |          | 
 BGE3   | character varying |           |          | 
 Trans  | character varying |           |          |
```